# What are the effects of sunscreen blocking low frequency electromagnetic wavelengths of sound?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, acoustics, wavelength

Sunscreens block uva and uvb rays but can they block sound waves?

Comment: Why do you think they would?

Comment: is sound electromagnetic?

Answer (score 2):

Sound is not an electromagnetic wave it is a pressure wave. So while a thick enough layer of sunscreen may reduce the intensity of the sound wave, it will not use the same physical principles as used in uva or uvb blockage.

Comment: But is it true that sound waves cannot excite molecules? Would that be because the wavelength is too big, or because the mechanism for energy transfer between molecules and wave is wrong for this?

Answer (score 1):

They can block waves of a type where the energy can be absorbed by the molecules inside the sunscreen, most likely by exciting their bonds and causing the atoms to vibrate more energetically. That is generally considered to be EM waves, and at that, EM waves of a particular wavelength, specifically similar to the size of the molecule.